# MySQL Inner Join Where column = (possible list of values)

Tags: mysql

Couldn't find an answer to this. Basically i have two tables like this:

Table 1:

```
id  name
 1   john
 2   bill
 3   tim
```

Table 2:

```
prodid value
  1     blar
  2     test
  3      meh
```

I want to do a join where I return the table2.value column, based on a list of values i specify for table1.name

So I have a list of values that are (john,tim)

I thought this would work:

```
select table2.value, table1.name 
from table2
inner JOIN
table1 on 
table2.prodid in (select id from table where name in ('john', 'tim'))
```

But this returns a huge amount of results and returns columns that are not in my list of names.

I'm sure its something silly, but any pointers to where im going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I would expect to just see values "blar" and "meh" from table 2 with the names "john" and "tim" next to them.

Answer (score 1):

A simple join with a filtering condition should do:

```
select
  t1.name,
  t2.value
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.prodid
where t1.name in ('john', 'tim')
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much for such a quick response and solution!